# Click a div using selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium

The website is: https://www.smile.one/merchant/mobilelegends?source=other

If you click any of the items from the below image, you get a green tick on that selection. See the 2 images.

[image]

After selection:

[image]

I am unable to perform this click using selenium.

This is what I am trying:

```
driver.get("https://www.smile.one/merchant/mobilelegends?source=other")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='sectionNav-cartao n107002' and @ga-data='1717']").click()
```

This raises an exception:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
```

I also tried to use the exact direct path using inspect element:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > mate > div.main-container > section > div.section-nav > div.sectionNav-list > div.sectionNav-cartao.n107002"))).click()
```

and got a `timeout` error.

I have also tried several other things but none of them seem to work. 
How do I perform this click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will use `XPath = "//div[@class='sectionNav-cartao n107002' and @ga-data='1717']"` there two elements present with the same XPath. Use a unique XPath like `XPath = "//div[@class='pc-nav']//div[@class='sectionNav-cartao n107002' and @ga-data='1717']"` which is highlighting only one element in chrome dev tool.

Code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.smile.one/merchant/mobilelegends?source=other")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='pc-nav']")))

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='pc-nav']//div[@class='sectionNav-cartao n107002' and @ga-data='1717']").click()
```